# Fixed panels while scrolling on a centered design

Tags: css

Okay, so I'd like to use a layout that has three divs (laid out as columns). The outer two will be navigation related, so I'd like them to remain in place as the user scrolls. The middle part will house the content, so it will need to scroll normally with the page.

I know you'd usually use position:fixed, but I'd like the whole design to be centered on the page. Using fixed positioning won't allow it to move horizontally like it should in a centered design. Anybody know of a way to meet all of that criteria?

I've setup a jsfiddle to get it started: http://jsfiddle.net/8RqEt/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `position:fixed; left: 50%; margin-left: ??px` on the outer elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/M5X7q/

- `left: 50%` centers the left edge of each element to the page: http://jsfiddle.net/M5X7q/1/
- Then, the correct amount of `margin-left` places each element where it needs to be.

Comment: Don't suppose there's any way to keep it from deforming when resizing smaller is there?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/M5X7q/3/ - but be warned: it might get irritating to work with, depending on what else needs to go on the page. For example, adding a footer will be difficult.

Comment: Ah it's so close! If only the blue boxes could trigger the page's horizontal scrollbars instead of just disappearing. I'm basically just trying to accomodate smaller resolutions, so maybe I should just serve them an alternate stylesheet. Thanks

Comment: I can't see how that can be fixed with CSS. Maybe I'm just overlooking something obvious.. With JavaScript to control the `top`: http://jsfiddle.net/M5X7q/4/

Answer (score 0):

I know you have your answer, but I wanted to improve upon my answer a bit for anyone else looking to solve something similar.

How 'bout this:

http://jsfiddle.net/M5X7q/6/

It scrolls the middle, fixes the blues, and triggers the scrollbars, plus it reduces the flicker I noticed in the fiddle just before your last note.

This uses a jquery plugin solution (I just corrected it to handle this case).  Not much js needed to accomplish this.

Here is the usage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.blue-1').scrollToFixed();
    $('.blue-2').scrollToFixed();
});
```

Here is a link to the plugin and its source:

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Comment: Oops.  Had to click the "show" button to see the last comment.  Didn't realize you guys got it.